# No results returned for web search automation in Python (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm aiming to get URLs as a results for my search_term. By running the below code in Python, my only output is []. Would someone be able to help to modify the code in order to receive the list with URLs to search results, ideally limited to first 10-20 URLs? Thanks in advance, please find the code below:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    browser = webdriver.Safari()
    browser.get(url)
    search_box = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    try:
        links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='web_regular_results']//h3//a")
    except: 
        links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3//a")
    results = []
    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute("href")
        print(href)
        results.append(href)
    browser.close()
    return results

get_results("fish")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided wrong xpath that is why you are not getting it.I have tried with chrome and change the xpath it is working fine.Try this and let know.

```
def get_results(search_term):
url = "https://www.google.com"
browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get(url)
search_box = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
search_box.send_keys(search_term)
search_box.submit()
try:
    links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a")
except:
    links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='r']/descendant::a")
print(len(links))
results = []
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
    results.append(href)
browser.close()
return results
```

get_results("fish")

Comment: Hi Kajal, I'm trying to avoid Chrome, so I used your suggestion above, and replaced webdriver.Chrome() with webdriver.Safari(), but then it returned 0 results. Would you know how to get this to work with Safari? Thanks!

Comment: Ok I’ll check and let you know.

Comment: I don't have safari browser 10 or above to verify the code I have updated the previous code.Try with safari this time and let me know whether it works.

Comment: Hi Kajal, it still shows 0 results when trying with Safari 12. Would there be any other way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share me safari 12 as I have safari 5.1.7 so can’t test and verify.If u could send the safari 12 then I can surely give you some solution.Thanks

Comment: Hi! Are you on Windows or Mac? I think 5.1.7 was the latest release for windows and since then there are no updates :(

Comment: Yes I am on Windows